# Woocommerce cart leads to cart_trashed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using
 `<?php echo wc_get_cart_url(); ?>` 
but instead of leading me to the cart page it leads me to cart_trashed. I am making a theme from scratch

Answer (score 1):

I found the mistake. I needed to change the cart page from the settings